# quarto change title for date entry in YAML header

Tags: quarto

I am using the following YAML header in my document

```
---
title: "Joker - Wahrscheinlichkeiten"
lang: de
date: today
format: html
---
```

This gives the following document header

[image: document header]

I would like to change the title above the date `VERÖFFENTLICHUNGSDATUM` to
`Erstellt am:`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In relation to the answer by @Julian checkout https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/title-blocks.html#metadata-labels

Answer (score 2):

You can use `published-title`:

```
---
title: "Joker - Wahrscheinlichkeiten"
lang: de
date: today
published-title: "Erstellt am:"
format: html
---
```